# how to build mutiple targets in a loop in animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

so i have made this nice animation within a loop. But if i put the curve object output in the loop, the target is the same. I want to create these columns in one loop and create a target for each column. is this possible with animation nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create multiple targets using object instancer and simplify this process using loop.

[image]

Comment: great thank you!!!!!